# call to page inside tab control via code

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I heed to create wizard and in the wizard I have tab control which have to call to the user control according to the context,I need to create the wizard which will able to invoke
different pages according to the user selection ,currently I call to the pages as follows which I think **is not the right way**,any Idea how should I do it **via code** (not in the xaml )i.e. according to some decision invoke the suitable page to the tab control.
this is the xaml:

```
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Name="MainBorder">
        <TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" Height="638" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TabItem Visibility="Collapsed" >
                <Frame Source="page1.xaml" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Visibility="Collapsed" >
                <Frame Source="page2.xaml"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Visibility="Collapsed" Header="Step 3">
                <TextBlock Text="Page 3"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Visibility="Collapsed" Header="Step 4">
                <TextBlock Text="Page 4"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Border>
```

**UPDATE**
I was tried in the main window like the following without success 
create new tab by code and add to it the page 1 and then add it to the MainTabControl

```
  TabControl tabControl = new TabControl(new Page1());
            MainTabControl.add..
```

.
there is no add in the main tab control

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, I would use a Frame rather that tabs. The frame allows you to manage the flow of it's content via the [**NavigationService**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use Uri's to display a page via the Frame.Source property, or a FrameworkElement via the Frame.Content property. Both are DependencyProperties and can therefore be bound to.

[**Paul Stovel**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57132/paul-stovell) wrote an excellent blog on this called [**WPF Navigation**](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation). Everything you need to create a wizard from a frame can be found in this blog, including passing values between pages and templating of the Frame to simply handle the display of navigation buttons.

Comment: I was reading the post and try to do something logically as he does without success :(...please see my updated post ,Any idea ?Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are looking to use a TabControl, you are looking at a command like MainTabControl.Items.Add(new TabItem() {Content = new UserControl()}); The TabControl is based on the ItemsControl, just like a ListBox, so its children, TabItem's, are added via the Items property or the ItemsSource property. The TabItem is based of a HeaderedContentControl which means it has a Header property and a Content property.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Mark, it is a lot easier to use `NavigationWindow`s than `TabControl`s.

I've worked on a lot of interfaces like this and written up some of the basic things with,

- [WPF Wizards, Part 1](http://alski.net/post/2012/01/11/WPF-Wizards.aspx)
- [WPF Wizards, Part 2](http://alski.net/post/2012/01/13/WPF-Wizards-part-2-Glass.aspx)

Then more recently I worked out how to get the styling just right

- [Styling Wizards](http://alski.net/post/2013/09/14/WPF-Re-creating-VS2012Office-2013-window-glow.aspx)

In fact I've released the styling and examples as open source at

- [image: WinChrome][WinChrome](http://winchrome.codeplex.com)

There is some simple example code including use of a navigation list to the left with,

- [image: WinChrome.Win7Demo] [WinChrome.Win7Demo](http://winchrome.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinChrome.Win7Demo/)

Hope this helps